# Add banner after the third post in wordpress 4.0

Tags: wordpress

How do I add a banner or a DIV with content after the third post on the index or category of Wordpress 4.0?

```
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next page navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );


            endif;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also make us of the inbuilt current_post property that is populated in WP_Query so it looks like:

```
// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    //count starts at 0
    if( $current_post == 2 ) : 
        echo '<div class="banner"><img src="your_banner_url" /></div>';
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 1;

// Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    if( $counter == 3 )
        echo '<div class="banner"><img src="your_banner_url" /></div>';

    $counter++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: The use of the counter property is unnecessary as WP_Query already provides a current_post variable to use for counting...